# Special characters in CDATA code block

Tags: special-characters, cdata

I'm trying to render a trademark(™) character in an XML file someone else has created.
The code is as follows:

```
<head><![CDATA[Product Name&#153;]]></head>
```

It currently fails to render the special character correctly.

I'm using UTF-8 encodin:

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: "fails to render the special character correctly" means what? What you get? What error message and from what tool?

Answer (score 5):

By definition, CDATA section content is taken as such, not parsed even for character references like `&#153;`. See [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Independently of this, `&#153;` is undefined, though commonly interpreted by browsers as denoting the trade mark character. Correct references for [trade mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) character are `&#8482;` and `&#x2122;`.

If the document encoding is UTF-8, you should enter the character “™” as such. Inside CDATA sections, it’s really the only way.